# Url is getting updated but navigation is not happening on button click in angular js

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am doing POC on login application using angular js. On button click I need to navigate to another page. The code which I have written is only updating the url but the view is not getting loaded. I have used ng-view or ui- view also. And I have used $location.path. But still unable to navigate to other page

Here is my code

index.html:

```
<html ng-app='myApp'>
<head>
    <title>Jasmine</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="routing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='content' ng-controller='LoginController'>
        <div class="container">
            <form class="form-signin" role="form" name="myForm" ng-submit="login()">
                <h3 class="form-signin-heading">Login Form</h3>
                <span>
                    <b>Username :</b>&nbsp; <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" required>
                </span> <br />
                <br /> <span>
                    <b>Password :</b>&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="password"
                                                         class="form-control" ng-model="user.password" required>
                </span>
                <br><br>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">
                    <b>Sign in</b>
                </button>
            </form>

        </div>

        {{message}}
    </div>
    <div ui-view></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here I have used ui-view.. when i use this, url is updating but not the view..
when i use ng-view, the script block is happening both in chrome and firefox.

routing.js:

```
var applog = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
applog.controller("LoginController", function ($scope, $location, $window) {
    $scope.message = "hi";
    $scope.login = function () {
        var username = $scope.user.name;
        var password = $scope.user.password;
        $location.path('/home');
    };
});

applog.controller("HomeController", function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.msg = "qwerty";
});

applog.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    }).when('/home', {
        templateUrl: '/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: 'index.html'
    });
});
```

Here I tried with hash also.. not working

Home.html:

```
<div ng-controller="HomeController">
  Welcome....
</div>
```